# mysql query to select data per hour

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build a query to get data per hour for a particular day(or today). 
I have a device data table that

```
#   Name                      Type      
    1  : idPrimary  --       int(11)                
    2 : inputDate   --      varchar(32) 
    3 : input1      --      varchar(11)     
    4 : input2      --      varchar(11)
```

And in inputDate   my data in this format :

```
SELECT inputDate FROM `deviceData` WHERE `inputDate` BETWEEN '2015-05-29 16:30:07' AND '2015-05-29 21:30:07' ORDER BY id
```

Showing rows 0 - 24 (3304 total, Query took 0.3487 seconds.)

```html
2015-05-29 16:30:09
2015-05-29 16:30:20
2015-05-29 16:30:25
2015-05-29 16:30:41
2015-05-29 16:30:46
2015-05-29 16:30:51
2015-05-29 16:30:56
2015-05-29 16:31:01
2015-05-29 16:31:07
2015-05-29 16:31:49
2015-05-29 16:31:54
2015-05-29 16:32:00
2015-05-29 16:32:10
2015-05-29 16:32:15
```

Now I want to take only one data in a hour, The minutes and seconds isn't important.For example :

```html
2015-05-29 5:*:*
2015-05-29 6:*:*
2015-05-29 7:*:*
2015-05-29 8:*:*
```

I don't know the best way to do this. I use regex but i can't do this.
Thanks

Comment: Do you need to do some aggregations on data for this hour? e.g. "select all rows between 1 and 2 hours and sum data in input1 ?

Comment: No actually i want to show last value of input 1 in each hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is hideous, but. Try this query :)

```
select * from (select substr(inputDate, 1, 13) as hours, input1 from deviceData order by inputDate desc) t GROUP BY hours;
```

I might ve messed up with sorting direction, though/

Comment: Thnx for your helping :))

Answer (score 0):

`select max(inputDate) from deviceData
group by date(inputDate),hour(inputDate);`

I think this must be helpful.